# Can I transform this VoIP box to become a wireless extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

(I was redirected from Network Engineering)

I have recently cancelled my internet phone and was wondering if it would be possible to turn the router, into a booster for my current LAN. It is already available to boost a wired connection but I don't know about WLAN.

Details:

Ethernet Port for Device, Router and Phone

Made by Vonage (Ask for more details if you need)

Software Version: 3.2.11-0.9.40

Hardware Version:VDV-23: 115

Model Number: VDV23-VU

When I was exploring the configuration page I found out that it supported Port Forwarding as well as Port Triggering, it also gave me the option to create a DMZ Host.

Sorry I do not know too much about this sort of thing, most of my knowledge of this is from server software.

My ultimate aim of this is to have two routers, one for an auth page, one for connection

Comment: Unless it has Wireless capabilities already then no. It sounds like you have an ATA (Analogue Telephone Adaptor), which have some limited built in routing capability but are not really full blown routers. The port forwarding is designed for the VoIP part and the reset is pretty much pass-through.

Comment: It seems to be able to recieve wireless @DavidPostill

Comment: https://support.vonage.co.uk/articles/Answer/Vonage-Box-VDV22VDV23-Advanced-Options-1043 makes no mention of Wireless.

Comment: https://www.vonage.co.uk/useful-info/beginners-guide/using-voip-with-wifi/
For incoming

Comment: That service is **not** provided by the ATA box. See https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Vonage+Wireless. Vonage are providing misleading information. Your link says it is possible, but not how it is done.

Comment: Note 1: I spent 5 years working VoIP tech support so I do know a little about how this stuff works :)

Comment: Note 2: "It is already available to boost a wired connection" ATAs don't **boost** anything. It might even be **slower** than your existing router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I transform this VoIP box to become a wireless extender?

No.

According to the [Vonage VDV23 Specification](https://www.cnet.com/products/vonage-box-voip-phone-adapter/specs/) it only provides Wired (Ethernet) connectivity:

> [image]

---

#### But [Can I use VoIP with wireless internet (WiFi)?](https://www.vonage.co.uk/useful-info/beginners-guide/using-voip-with-wifi/) says it is possible!

That Vonage article is misleading, it says:

> The simple answer to this question is yes, but it's a little bit more complicated than that. If you have a wireless router and network then you can use your VoIP phone in a wireless way. If you're on the move, you can use VoIP via WiFi connections but you will need to arrange this with your VoIP provider and it may cost more. There's also the possibility of setting up a WiMAX extender which boosts transmissions up to 75 km, so can use your normal VoIP connections locally.

Note that is doesn't actually say how do this and what hardware/software is required.

This article sheds some light on the subject:

> [Vonage Wireless Internet Service](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Vonage+Wireless)
>
> As far as wireless Vonage Internet service is concerned, there are
>   only a handful of ways that Vonage VoIP phone service can be described
>   as offering any sort of wireless functionality:
>
> - A wireless router with Vonage phone service, allowing customers to create a home wireless Internet service, or local area network
>     (LAN).
> - Vonage's VoIP mobile app with a cellphone, enabling access to a wireless Vonage network connection point through a 3G/4G data network
>     or a WiFi connection point.
> - Using wireless phone jacks to support multiple phones in one household.
> - A Vonage softphone that supports not only wireless but essentially phoneless (no physical, traditional phone) access to
>     Vonage's VoIP phone service.

Some Wireless Routers have an integrated VoIP Adapter, for example:

> Some of the wireless routers with an integrated VoIP phone adapter
>   that are compatible with Vonage service are:
>
> - D-Link VWR
> - Motorola VT2542
> - Linksys WRTP54G

Note:

- The Vonage VDV23-VU ATA (Analogue Telephone Adaptor) is an ATA with limited built in routing capabilities. It is **not** a Wireless Router with a built in ATA.